# passing csrf_token through dynamically-generated form

Tags: javascript, django

I have a reddit-style threaded messageboard app which includes the functionality to reply in-line to comments via a separate javascript function.

In the template file there is a link after each post:

`<a href="{% url 'posts:comment' post_id=post.id %}" onclick="quick_reply(this, '{% url 'posts:comment' post_id=post.id %}'); return false;">reply</a>`

The quick_reply function that generates the form is in a self-contained javascript file:

```
function quick_reply(element, formURL){
...

quickReplyForm.innerHTML =
...
        "<div class=\"quick-reply-wrapper\">"+
            "<form method=\"post\" action=\""+formURL+"\">"+
                    "<label for=\"id_subject\">Subject</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"subject\" name=\"subject\" id=\"id_subject\" maxlength=\"100\"/><br/>"+
                    "<label for=\"id_body\">Body</label><textarea name=\"body\" id=\"id_body\"></textarea><br/>"+
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"submit\"/>"+
                    "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Never mind...\" class=\"button\" onclick=\"quickReplyTransition.toggle();\"/>"+
            "</form>"+
        "</div>";

...
}
```

(for clarity I have removed the other code from that function which is just dealing with visual effects)

At the moment submitting the contents of the form generates a 'CSRF verification failed' error - but how can I pass through the csrf token from the template so that it can be placed in the dynamically-generated form?

I can see that one answer would be to include the javascript function within the template file itself and add the form field there, but I would prefer to keep this in a separate javascript file in the static app if at all possible.

Can this be done? I've seen other examples for jQuery but not sure how to relate them to this custom js.

Comment: Embed the token as a input field in your template. Then edit the code above to fetch it and output it in a hidden field.

Comment: I've added ```{% csrf_token %}``` to the template at the start of the <body> tag, and then the following line to the above javascript at the start of the form: ```"<input id=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+document.getElementById('csrfmiddlewaretoken').value+"\" ></input>"+``` I'm still getting the same verification failed error though - is this close to what you're recommending?

Comment: Just saw my error - changed it to ```"<input name=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value+"\" ></input>"+``` and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: my only comment would be that the input tags are singular. They don't have closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

1. Use input tag with csrf value int it. Send this value to backend with the correct name.
   `<input name="csrf" value="somevalue" hidden>`

   OR
2. Set `CSRF-Token` header value with csrf token in your ajax request.

At the time of rendering store the csrf value in meta tag and use that value with every request. Like `<meta name="csrf" content="somevalue" />`

You will get csrf value from your backend at the time of page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a hidden input element in the template file and set its value first from there,

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="somevalue" id="csrf">`

Within your quick reply function, collect that value using a query selector method or any selector you like,

`const csrfToken = document.querySelector("#csrf").value;`

and finally when you generate the dynamic form pass the token again with a hidden type input element to the div block.

`<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_csrf\" value=\"${csrfToken}\">`

Comment: Mark code with backticks. Example: `my code`.

Comment: ```comprehended```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form.html#csrfexemptmixin) if you are using a class-based view